# I want to have a command (preferred runing from a script) that clears the screen, saves it and restores it later

Tags: command-line, restore

[Save all command and all output (using script across terminals)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097720/save-all-command-and-all-output-using-script-across-terminals)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685165/how-to-clear-the-terminal-in-script-while-restoring-entered-commands-after-scrip

These are links I visited but didn't made me sutisfied.
I want to copy ALL of the terminal's content and clear the screen. after doing my thing I want the old content be written back to the shell.

Comment: Have you tried `tput`? ... If yes, then would you explain why it did not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: because I don't want the lag of resetting the terminal. I only want two lines being removed. one of them to be replaced with an out put of: "$PS1sudo apt install vim"

Comment: and the other just to be deleted and the output of the next commnands will replace it.

Comment: link to the terminal output I want to modify: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-from-2022-07-24-12-54-59.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a program quit with "q" and restore the console like "man" does?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415863/how-do-i-make-a-program-quit-with-q-and-restore-the-console-like-man-does)